# Money "to buy it" or "to buy it *with*"

Tags: prepositions

> There was no hurry, for there was nowhere to go, nothing to buy and no money to buy it **with**, […]
>   (Harper Lee, To Kill A Mockingbird)

Is *with* bound to *be there*. or can we avoid using *with*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say *no money to buy it* (you can also say *no money with which to buy it*, or *no money for buying it*, or *no money you could buy it with*, or any number of things); but *buy it with* is just a touch more Alabama-colloquial. Moreover, the dactyl (DA da da) keeps the sentence flowing over the comma into the next phrase down to *see*, where just *buy it* would put in a little, interruptive hiatus, as if there were a dash instead of a comma:

> People moved slowly then. They ambled across the square, shuffled in and out of the stores around it, took their time about everything. A day was twenty-four hours long but seemed longer. There was no hurry, for there was nowhere to go, nothing to buy and no money to buy it with, nothing to see outside the boundaries of Maycomb County.